# Is it possible to test a Cloudflare App with Worker before submitting?

Tags: cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-apps

After clicking “Add app” on the /apps/developer/app-creator page if I click “Save draft” I am given a message “You are not authorized to create apps with workers.”

Is there a way I can create an App that contains a worker for testing on my own domains? How do I become authorized to create an app with a worker? Is it possible to have an App that is only a worker and no client side javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only test installing an app with a worker if you have been accepted into the beta. You can apply for the beta here: https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-workers/#otherways 
Yes, it is possible to just have workers installed on no client-side javascript. Just omit the "resources" node

Comment: That link doesn't seem to offer any way to sign up for the beta to test a Worker in a Cloudflare App. How can we apply to the beta?